# Designer Issue + Entity Framework (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Background, this is a WPF project that uses the entity framework which when run works fine, it is just the designer which gives the following error.

Unhandled exception
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

I have coped the connection string to the UI but this is still a problem

I have the following binding

```
   DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static ViewModel:ViewModelLocator.MainWindowViewModelStatic}}"
```

Which relates to a class which initialises

```
     new MainWindowViewModel(new UIDataProvider());
```

which has the following

```
    private readonly IUIDataProvider _dataProvider;

    private IList<Customer> _customers;

    public IList<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_customers == null)
            {
                GetCustomers();
            }
            return _customers;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(IUIDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;

        Tools = new ObservableCollection<ToolViewModel>();
        Tools.Add(new AToolViewModel());
        Tools.Add(new BToolViewModel());
    }


    private void GetCustomers()
    {
        _customers = _dataProvider.GetCustomers();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer actually instantiates your code at design time.  Your code is, upon instantiation, attempting to access your data, and so the Entity Framework code is looking in the wrong place for your connection string.  The solution is to not do that at design mode.

The naive method is to check [DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx).  This isn't really MVVM, as you have to check this in your view model, and that injects UI code into your view model.

What's the solution?  You can just hold your nose and do it (quick and dirty), create an inject-able interface which abstracts this check from your ViewModel, which is by-default an implementation that checks that DependencyProperty, or you catch the exception and swallow it gracefully.

Comment: The problem if I am reading this correctly is 

_mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(new UIDataProvider());
        

AS this initialises 

       public class UIDataProvider : IUIDataProvider
       {
        private NorthwindEntities _northwindEntities
            = new NorthwindEntities();

        public IList<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return _northwindEntities.Customers.ToList();
        }
    
Is there any way I can use a null / dummy version?

Comment: @user3532702: As I said, the problem is that this code is running in the designer.  The solution is to not run the code in the designer.  The problem should now be "How do I not run this code in the designer", the answer to which I've provided you (not the code, but the concept).  You have to 1. identify that you are NOT at runtime but are in fact at design time, and 2. not execute code that touches the database.  I've given you a link that tells you how to detect design time in a WPF app.  Use it directly, or abstract it from your view model.

Comment: @user3532702: Side note, you don't have to work hard to use it.  The following will return `true` when called in your code within the designer:  `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());`

Comment: I changed a few things around as instructed and it worked, thank you


  if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            {
                if  (_northwindEntities == null)
                {
                    _northwindEntities = new NorthwindEntities(); 
                }
                
                return _northwindEntities.Customers.ToList();
            }
            else
            {

Comment: @user3532702: Side note, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23064774/edit) to add the info in your answer below, or in general, when adding further details.  SO isn't a forum; questions should contain the question, and the answers should only be answers to the question.  Yeah, we're kinda anal about that stuff :/

Comment: I can see that :-), where and what exactly do you need me to add, I posted the change recommended

Comment: @user3532702: Thanks.  As a new user, if you have too many deleted/downvoted questions or answers, you can get autoblocked by the system.  Don't forget to check out the [help], and lurking [meta] wouldn't hurt.